# Exposing mysql with ngrok and connecting with Datagrip (WSL2)

Tags: mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ngrok, datagrip, wsl-2

I have a WSL2 set up on my development machine. It has a mysql server running and I can see the DB and Schemas correctly if I use a DB viewer from within the WSL "VM", that is, if I open up the mysql cli or even Datagrip/IDEA from the WSL it sees the DB correctly on localhost:3306.

I also have a Datagrip installation on Windows which I want to use to connect to the mysql db. Since WSL2 has changed how networking works, connecting to localhost:3306 doesn't work - so I need to bridge the WSL2 network to my Windows network. 
I've found several solutions, but I've already been using ngrok successfully for local web sites.

Supposedly, running `./ngrok tcp 3306` in the ubuntu shell exposes the WSL2 mysql instance outside with a specific url+port (which it gives me back). 
The problem is that I can't seem to connect to it via Datagrip, is there some specific configuration I need to run in order for it to work?

e.g:

ngrok tells me:   `tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:11497 -> localhost:3306`

if I try to connect to that url in Datagrip, it times out.

Comment: First of all you need to ensure that you can connect to MySQL instance via native cli. After that to check whether TCP enabled or not. Could you do that?

Comment: Have you tried suggestion mentioned in my previous comment?